# Do the genus, codimension and projective space weights determine a Fano threefold?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, birational-geometry, projective-varieties

Say I have a complex Fano threefold of some given codimension, some given genus, embedded into some (possibly weighted) projective space.

My question is: do the genus, codimension and weights of the projective space always uniquely determine a Fano threefold, or do I need more data?

For example, according to the Graded Ring Database, if we pick genus $0$ and codimension $1$, then there are $32$ such Fano threefolds. From a quick inspection, it seems that the weights of the projective spaces that they're embedded into seem different for each Fano threefold. So I'd hazard a guess that the genus, codimension and weights are the only data we need. Is this true?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. For instance
$$
X = \mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1
$$
and a smooth $(1,1)$-divisor
$$
Y \subset \mathbb{P}^2 \times \mathbb{P}^2
$$
both a Fano threefolds of genus 25 in codimension 4 with all weights equal to 1.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - I realised I forgot to add that I'm looking at index $1$ Fano threefolds in the question. Is the additional specification of index $1$ now enough?

Comment: If you want an example of index 1, just take the blowups of $X$ and $Y$ at elliptic curves obtained as intersections of two half-anticanonical divisors. These are Fano threefolds of type 3-7 and 4-1 in https://fanography.pythonanywhere.com/

Comment: I see - thanks again